# Understanding a Query function error message

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to pull the data from 2 dates only but I am getting a error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: A

Here is the query function  that I used:
`QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(FORMULA!A2,"RawData6.4.23!A2:I500"), "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I where I > '2023-04-05' and I < '2023-04-06'")`
How can I resolve this issue?
Thx

Comment: If column I is a date field, there are no dates both greater than 2023-04-05 and less than 2023-04-06.

Comment: You seem to be expecting `IMPORTRANGE` to return a set of rows.  That's not how it works.  `IMPORTRANGE` stands alone and replaces cells in the current sheet with the imported data.  You would need `QUERY` to be in a separate cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `Col#` notation and you also need the `date` keyword when working with dates. Try this out:

```cpp
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(FORMULA!A2,"RawData6.4.23!A2:I500"), 
   "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9
    where Col9 > date '2023-04-05' and Col9 < date '2023-04-06'")
```

Comment: Thanks Z.. very much your answer to my issue it worked perfectly.